# uart received data decoding in pic microcontroller

Tags: arrays, byte, decode, pic, uart

I am interfacing an HMI TFT screen with PIC 16F877A, and this screen has a protocol to send and receive data. I want to decode the received data to read the required information without any extra values. I have thought about saving the received data by making an array and save data in it, and take the required byte that I want to read.
This is the protocol of the TFT, and below is the designed code.
`AA 78 00 01 0F CC 33 C3 3C`  (I want to read the part of (`0F`) only)

```c
int uart_rd;  //UART read variable
typedef unsigned char INT8U;
typedef unsigned long INT32U;

void Read_Bytes(INT8U *str, INT32U Num) {
    INT32U i;
    for (i = 0; i < Num; i++) {
        str[i++] = UART1_Read();
    }
}

void main() {
UART1_Init(115200);  //Uart baud at 115200
    while (1) {          // Endless loop

        if (UART1_Data_Ready() == 1) {
            Read_Bytes(str_read, 9);
            uart_rd = str_read[3];

            if (uart_rd == 0x0F) {
                PORTB.B2 = 1;
            }
            else {
                PORTB.B2 = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is not cleared. But I am assuming you need to know why 0x0F is not detected. 
From your code AA 78 00 01 0F CC 33 C3 3C, 0x0F is at 4th position from left when AA is indexed at 0.

So, `uart_rd = str_read[4];` for 0x0F.

In your Read_Bytes function you are starting to save data from str[1] because str[i++] will be str[1] at start when i = 0.

Hence, `uart_rd = str_read[5];` for 0x0F